# Are js special characters fixed in size?

Tags: java

I have the requirements to add special characters in the order field of the particular application. The field accepts letters a-z and numbers 0-9. Now they need to include special characters so my question is: Is there a fixed number of special characters in Java or does special characters mean anything inputted from the keyboard?

This is how we are adding alphabet and numbers in the order field now I need to include special characters in the string variable `test`:

```
var test =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
```

```html
-, /, \, #, *
```

Comment: A Java characters can be any of the UTF-16 character so yeah... depending on how you define "special character", there might be a few...

Comment: Javascript is not Java. Please remove the tag.

Comment: so you removed javascript tag but changed the title to refer to js instead of java. Bit contradicting, right?

Comment: `var test = ...` - So you are a person of Java 10... I see...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If considering the 128-ASCII, characters ranging from value 32 to 47 you may consider as special characters. But if are considering 256-ASCII then you can have many more. If you are considering UTF-8 or UTF-16 there can be even more. There isn't any fixed number of special characters. To resolve this, I think you need to modify your requirement to make it clear what particular special characters need to be added in the list. You can get better ideas about special characters from following links.

http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Entering_special_characters

Comment: why 32-47, and not some other range? and where do you get the name `128-ASCII` and `256-ASCII` from? there is `ASCII`, `ASCII-7` and `US-ASCII`, but I don't think `128-ASCII` exists

Comment: also, I find it not likely they would explicitly want to accept for example space (32), but not underscore (95). Seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses UTF-16 internally, so yes, there is fixed number of possible characters - [1,112,064 valid code points of Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

But in practice, you will have to ask what they mean by special characters. There is no standard definition: it can mean a small subset, entire unicode, or anything else. Since it is an order field it is probably some specific, small subset.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed number of 'special' characters. You will need to ask the one, who gave you that task, what they mean exactly.

Comment: thank you very much , i ask them and now i have the clear requirements. this community rocks.

Comment: You are welcome. It is always a good idea, to ask for precise requirements instead of guessing. Guessing is mosten times wrong and it's the developer's fault in the end. If the requirements turn out wrong in the end, it's the clients fault ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int c=32; c<128; c++) {
        System.out.println(c + ": " + (char)c);
}
```

Execute the above code, you will get a list of all ascii characters allowed in java, then you can use them to define your set of valid characters.

Comment: thank you for great help on understanding special charcaters

Comment: The fact that ASCII exists is not very relevant to Java. `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. It takes a lot of explaining to relate that over to ASCII for the characters for which that is meaningful.